# How to create Struts Drop down List?

Tags: struts

I m new to struts.

I Want to add drop down in web page.That drop down should contain four values. The default and first value will be (Select).

I want to persist the selected value, when that form is opened again and while submitting, if user doesn't select any value from drop down (meaning the default value is present) I want to give an alert to the user and then not to allow a submit  until till the user selects an option from the dropdown.

There is one action.java, form.java, javascript file and jsp file. In action.java, I m suppose to use ArrayList to hold different drop down values. How this can be done. please help me.

Comment: Are you using Struts or struts2?

Answer (score 2):

```
<s:select list="#{'':'Select', 'key1':'Value 1', 'key2':'Value 2'}" key="selectedValue"></s:select>
```

or you have a list object(id, value)

```
<s:select key="selectedValue" list="yourlists" headerKey="" headerValue="Select" listKey="id" listValue="value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to show your code here. If you are interested in tutorials then I'd suggest - **[VaanNila](http://www.vaannila.com/index.html)**, a great place to learn struts framework. ([Here](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-html-select-tag-example-1.html) is a link of **select** tag.)